# Upper estimate of integral

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I have the following integral defined on $\mathbb{C}$ of a function taking values in a Banach algebra.

$$\int_{\mid z \mid =\mid \sigma(M) +\delta\mid }(z-M)^{-1}z^{n}d\bar{z}=M^n$$
where $d\bar{z}=\frac{dz}{2i\pi}$

How come we have
$$|M^n| \le 
    \left( \max_{\mid z \mid =\mid \sigma(M) +\delta\mid }
       \left| (z-M)^{-1}\right|\right)
    \left(\mid \sigma(M) +\delta\mid \right)^{n+1} ?$$

Comment: edited to the best of ability, please double check

Comment: I guess you integrate along the circle with radius $r(M)+\delta$ where $r(M)$ is the spectral radius of $M$, right? If it is so, then I think there is a constant missing ($2\pi$, to be more precise).

Comment: @MaoWao the measure is normlised w.r.t 2pi , I forgot to mention that. But I had troubles with the estimaste of z^n i guess its just $\mid r(M)+ \delta \mid ^{n}$

Comment: Just take the norm of the integrand. The additional factor $r(M)+\delta$ comes from the length of the contour line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As MaoWao suggests ;
Just take the norm of the integrand. The additional factor r(M)+δr(M)+δ comes from the length of the contour line.